# AWS Python SDK Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

Is there a way to use Boto3 client in python to check processes running on a AWS EC2 Windows instance? Also is it possible to start an application on a AWS Windows EC2 instance using the boto3 Python SDK?

Comment: I am afraid the answer is: No and No.

Comment: Seconded; no - and no. This type of question is not a good SO format as well.

Comment: so.... task manager but through `boto3`? AFAIK, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a process on an EC2 instance using the AWS System Manager service, which you can [call via Boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ssm.html). Note that this requires you to have the SSM agent running on the EC2 instance.

Checking the processes running on an EC2 instance might be a bit more difficult. I suppose you could execute something like a `ps` command (not sure what the equivalent is in Windows) via the SSM service, and then parse the output in the response your Python function receives.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this approach!!